# How can i Escape from "no source available" errors when stepping OVER a stdio function in eclipse (C language, using CDT)

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm using eclipse to write C code and attempting to debug code using the eclipse debugger/

While debugging it gives me `"No source available"` errors, when I'm trying to step over stdio functions.  I have included `stdio.h`

Is there a way to ignore these errors?

They're not actually causing the program to crash (that's caused by a segfault elsewhere), but I'd like to look into what's happening with eclipse's tools rather than going through cygwin and GDB.

Answer (score 0):

A. Eclipse uses GDB on linux for its debugging generally speaking.
B. Try 'next', 'step over' or 'finish' if you are within a stdio function instead of 'step into'.